# Coin Recognition from Parallel Coin acceptor to Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano

I have one project to do where I have one big problem and I need your help. At this stage, it is not a problem for me to write Arduino program for a money receiver who has an impulse output. But the coin receivers that have a parallel output lines which is described in the manuals in detail how it comes to information in the cables of the coin drop, but I can not hit on a decision on how to program Arduino to know coin type, I hope you any of you have a similar experience and will be able indicating which way to raise in order to get to work this project. Coin model is:

> EMP 800 v6
> [Link to the manual](https://veq.ru/files/equipment/WH_Munzprufer_EMP_800.pdf)

Any your suggestions may be the my life saver...
Thank you in advance guys...

Comment: The biggest problem I see is programming the coin-collector. I think you can make it learn coins with only the dip-switches, but other options seem to only be programmable by PC. The outputs of the coin-collector are simple open collector outputs. So connect the ground to the ground of the Arduino, and the open-collector outputs to the Arduino inputs, and add/enable a pull-up resistor. When a coin is accepted, the input pin will read a short LOW pulse.

Comment: Nice Suggestion.   I  will try this for next week and I will inform you what will happen

Comment: @Gerben Programming coins on Coin Acceptor is not problem for me I m working in Service Center where my main work is programming Coin and Bill Acceptors and I have all programmers that I need including this EMP's programmer and PC Software too... But problem is output for this channels(1,2,3,4,5,6) I think is different then normal Pulse Output. Pulse gives output by getting Low in 50 - 100 MS one time and that means its 1 impulse but this parallel output I think is difference then IMPULSE ;(

Comment: From my reading the datasheet, I gathered that you get a Pulse output on the channel that corresponds to the coin that's being recognized. Fer example, if channel 3 is for a 10cent coin, then you get a LOW pulse on channels 3's output pin.